# Number of elements of order $p$ in $GL_{2}(\Bbb Z_{p})$, where $p$ is a prime.

Tags: group-theory

How many elements of order $p$ are there in $GL_{2}(\Bbb Z_{p})$, where $p$ is a prime$?$.

I could find only one such element, which is an upper triangular matrix with two diagonal and one super diagonal entry $=1$. Do there exist more elements of order $p?$

Comment: What about the transpose?

Comment: Presumably you mean $\Bbb Z_p = \Bbb Z/p$, not the $p$-adic integers, right?

Comment: It's better (and unambiguous) to write ${\rm GL}_2({\mathbb F}_p)$ or just ${\rm GL}_2(p)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{pmatrix}1&k\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&nk\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, so you can replace the super diagonal $1$ by $k\ne0\in\Bbb Z_p$.

Plus you can do  a subdiagonal version.

There are others too.

Answer (score 3):

If $M$ has order $p$ then its minimal polynomial divides $X^p-1=(X-1)^p$; and so is $(X-1)^2$. So by the Jordan Canonical Form Theorem all elements of order $p$ are conjugate to $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

To see how many conjugates this element has we must calculate the size of its centraliser: this is an easy calculation, the centraliser is just the set of all $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$, where $a\not=0$.

The whole group has order $(p^2-1)(p^2-p$); the centraliser has order $(p-1)p$.

There are therefore $(p^2-1)$ elements of order $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $GL_{2}(\Bbb Z_{p})$ contains $p+1$ Sylow p-subgroups and each of the them contains $p-1$ elements of order $p$, then the total number of elements of order $p$ in $GL_{2}(\Bbb Z_{p})$ is equal to $(p+1)(p-1)=p^{2}-1$.